# I am not able to understand the free body diagram for the bottom figure

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, free-body-diagram

PS: This is taken from:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force

I am not able to understand the free body diagram for the non-inertial frame of reference.It would be of great help if someone could break it down and explain what is happening.

> Top figure: accelerating car of mass M with passenger of mass m. The force from the axle is (m + M)a. In the inertial frame, this is the only force on the car and passenger.
>
> Center figure: an exploded view in the inertial frame. The passenger is subject to the accelerating force ma. The seat (assumed of negligible mass) is compressed between the reaction force –ma and the applied force from the car ma. The car is subject to the net acceleration force Ma that is the difference between the applied force (m + M)a from the axle and the reaction from the seat −ma.
>
> Bottom figure: an exploded view in the non-inertial frame. In the non-inertial frame where the car is not accelerating, the force from the axle is balanced by a fictitious backward force −(m + M)a, a portion −Ma applied to the car, and −ma to the passenger. The car is subject to the fictitious force −Ma and the force (m + M)a from the axle. The sum of these forces ma is applied to the seat, which exerts a reaction −ma upon the car, so zero net force is applied to the car. The seat (assumed massless) transmits the force ma to the passenger, who is subject also to the fictitious force −ma, resulting in zero net force on the passenger. The passenger exerts a reaction force −ma upon the seat, which is therefore compressed. In all frames the compression of the seat is the same, and the force delivered by the axle is the same.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fictitious forces, $-(m + M)a$ in this example, only appear in a non-inertial or accelerating reference frame, here on attached to the accelerating car.  To an observer in this frame (a passenger in the car) the car is at rest so there must be a force equal to and opposite to the force from the wheels/axle, and that is the fictitious force.  Fictitious forces do not appear in an inertial (non accelerating) reference frame, such as one attached to an observer stationary on the ground. To this observer the only force is that of the wheels/axle and that force accelerates the car forward.

For rotating non-inertial reference frames, other fictitious forces appear, such as the centrifugal and Coriolis forces.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It helped a lot.

Comment: Glad this helped!  Fictitious forces are confusing when you first encounter them.